# Lookup field is not autopopulating

Tags: lookup

I have two objects. `Case` and `Child__c` objects. I have case lookup on `Child__c` object.
When creating a `Child__c` record from case related list, `Case` lookup on `Child__c` record is not auto populating.
This is happening only for one profile users. For admin profile it is working fine.

Any idea what could be the reason?

Comment: Does the profile have access to the parent field?

Comment: Not working for one profile leads me to think it is a permission issue.